# How to get values of a django query from attributes of a many to many relation?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have these two models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class User(models.Model):
    ACCES_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('ADMIN', 'Admin'),
        ('GUEST', 'Guest')
    )
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='users')
    access_type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=ACCES_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

I want a query that would return the values of the number of users with `access_type == GUEST` and the number of users with `access_type == ADMIN` for each company, like this:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Company name', 'admin_users': 3, 'guest_users': 1}]>
```

I tried some approaches with annotate but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [**`filter=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate-filter) in a [**`Count`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Company.objects.annotate(
    admin_users=Count('users', filter=Q(access_type='ADMIN')),
    guest_users=Count('users', filter=Q(access_type='GUEST'))
)
```

The `Company` objects that arise from this will have two extra attributes: `.admin_users` and `.guest_users`.